# Changing in-mem H2 database to embedded persistence and found some problems?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, persistence, h2, jhipster

I have inherited an app and it's called Hospital. Currently it's a Spring Boot app created with JHipster with in-mem database jdbc:h2:mem:hospital. Previously it works fine with the h2 database embedded and accessible at http://localhost:8080/h2-console/. And I am running this app in a Docker container. But after I made the changes for a file-based persistence I ran into issues.

First the H2 console at http://localhost:8080/h2-console/ is not accessible with error message "H2 Console Sorry, remote connections ('webAllowOthers') are disabled on this server." I made the changes and docker compose up the app, although the app is running, the H2 Console is still not accessible with the same error.

Here are the changes I made: First, I made the changes to application.yml(these are lines added, it was not in the original file): 'spring: application: name: hospital profiles: active: prod jmx: enabled: false data: jpa: repositories: bootstrap-mode: deferred datasource: type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource url: jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo username: sa password: hikari: poolName: Hikari auto-commit: true h2: console: enabled: true datasource: url: jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo username: sa password: driverClassName: org.h2.Driver**' Next, I also make changes in application-prod.yml, since I am using Prod profile as active: 'spring: devtools: restart: enabled: false livereload: enabled: false datasource: type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource # url: jdbc:h2:file:./h2db/hospital;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 #url: jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 url: jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo; username: sa password: hikari: poolName: Hikari auto-commit: true h2: console: enabled: true settings: web-allow-others: true jpa: database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect database: H2 show-sql: false properties: hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false hibernate.generate_statistics: false liquibase: # Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically contexts: prod, faker`' I also made changes to .h2.server.properties(I made these changes even though I am running H2 in Embedded Persistence mode, just to be safe): #H2 Server Properties #Sun Dec 17 12:11:59 GMT 2023 0=JHipster H2 (Disk)|org.h2.Driver|jdbc:h2:file:/Users/tlim/data/demo|hospital webSSL=false webAllowOthers=true webPort=8080 What else need to be configured and what have I done wrong? I was expecting for persistence to file for H2 database to be successful. Also expected to open the jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo in H2 Console to be successful.

I was expecting for persistence to file for H2 database to be successful. Also expected to open the jdbc:h2:file:~/data/demo in H2 Console to be successful.